# fast logging solution for nodejs command line app

Tags: node.js, performance, logging, node-modules, winston

I've been building a node js based command line app in which it executes a set of tasks in sequence and prints texts to the terminal continuously. When I tried analysing the performance, most of the time the event loop is blocked by the logs printed on the terminal and this is very slow in windows.

I've tried `winston` and I didn't find any way to optimize the performance when using winston. Then I checked `pino`, but the problem is I can't force users to use another command to just pretty print the log as the logs are very crucial in this app.

Is there any library or any optimisation that I can do to improve the performance of logging without sacrificing usability?

Answer (score 1):

pino very fast https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino

```
const logger = require('pino')({
    level: 'debug',
    prettyPrint: true
 });
logger.debug('Hello')
logger.error('Hello')
logger.info('Hello')
```

Comment: Could you please add a little explanatin for everyone to understand the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try  "log4js" npm library to have logs of the application. you can write it in file. Its performance is better than winston

Comment: As per the below link, it is not.
https://www.loggly.com/blog/benchmarking-popular-node-js-logging-libraries/